# Solving an equation for formal power series over complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers, formal-power-series

I want to solve the equation $x^2+z-1=0$ in the ring $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$ which is the set of formal power series over the variable $z$ over the complex numbers.

I also have to prove that there are no solutions in $\mathbb{C}[z]$.

I think that I should somehow write my equation with power series something like $a(z)x^2+b(z)x+c(z)$ for the first part but I'm not sure what to do after this and how to write it like that.

I also know that if $\alpha$ is a root in $\bar{f}(x)$ with multiplicity one, then $f(x)$ has a root $a(z)\in\mathbb{C}[[z]]$ with $a_0=\alpha$.

Comment: You can take $x=\pm (1-z)^{1/2}$ and then expand this as a [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) with $\alpha = 1/2$.

Comment: So I should write the $x$ as a binomial series which would be a solution in $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$?

Comment: Yes, expanding $(1 - z)^{1/2}$ as a series will give you a solution in $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$.  If you don't like generalized binomial coefficients, it's equivalent to computing its Taylor series centered at $0$.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that
How about proving there is no solution in $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$?

Comment: No solution in $\Bbb C[z]$ because $1-z$ is an indecomposible (irreducible) element of the polynomial ring and therefore doesn’t have a square root there.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly: the whole thing ($x^2+1-z$) won't have a square root because of $1-z$ not having one and therefore there is no solution?

Comment: @Alice A solution $x$ to $x^2 + z - 1 = 0$ satisfies $x = \pm \sqrt{1 - z}$, so $x$ is a square root of $1 - z$.  That's what Lubin is getting at.

Comment: Ah so $\pm\sqrt{1-z}\not\in\mathbb{C}[z]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a power series $f\in\mathbb C[[z]]$ such that $f(z)^2+z-1=0$. Write $f(z)=a_0+a_1z+\cdots$ and then identify the coefficients: $a_0^2=1$, $2a_0a_1=-1$, $2a_0a_2+a_1^2=0$, and so on. As you can see $a_0\ne0$ and then can find $a_1,a_2,\dots$ step by step.

If instead $f\in\mathbb C[z]$, then from $f(z)^2=1-z$ you get, by taking degrees, that $2\deg f=1$, a contradiction.